# If a C++ class has dynamic allocation within a class method but has no constructor/destructor or any non-static members, is it still a POD type?

Tags: c++, oop, static, polymorphism, dynamic-memory-allocation

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class A
{
    public:
        int index;
        int init(int type);
}

int A::init(int type)
{
    Interface* interface = SelectInterface(type);
    int index = interface->get_index(type);
    delete interface;
}
```

And then I have the following interface:

```
// ----------- INTERFACES -------------- //

class Interface
{
    virtual int get_index() = 0;
}

// This is the interface factory
Interface* SelectInterface(int type)
{
    if (type == 0)
    { 
        return new InterfaceA();
    }
    else if (type == 1)
    {
        return new InterfaceB();
    }

    return null;
}

class InterfaceA :: public Interface
{
    InterfaceA();
    int get_index();
} 

int InterfaceA::get_index()
{
    return 5;
}

class InterfaceB :: public Interface
{
    InterfaceB();
    int get_index();
} 

int InterfaceB::get_index()
{
    return 6;
}
```

Class A does not have any constructors or destructors, or any non-static data members. However Class A does dynamically allocate an object and then delete it within a class method.

**Is Class A still a POD (plain old data) type?**

Comment: FWIW, There is no such thing as POD in C++11+.  There is standard layout, and trivial types, which yours would be the former.

Comment: For POD objects the compiler allocates them in static memory. Do either of standard layout/ trivial types ensure that the object would be allocated in static memory?

Comment: Quick google search results in -> "Trivial is intended to capture the support for static initialization"

Comment: What do you mean static memory?  Are you talking about the "stack", or the read only data section of the executable?

Comment: I am talking about the stack. It would be best if the object could be in read only data but as I am using run-time polymorphism I believe this is not possible.

Comment: You don't need a POD object to be on the stack.  If you don't create the object with `new` it will be on the stack.

Comment: So in the example code above the only object which is created on heap is the interfaceA method which is deleted soon after. If Class A was not created with new then the only thing on stack is interfaceA?

Comment: Yep.  If you don't use new (or a smart pointer) then you're not using the heap.

Comment: From your comments it seems like this is a xy problem. Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and try to avoid it next time.

Comment: True....will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not relevant what the member function `init` is doing or not. That does not affect whether A is a POD type or not (in your example it is).

POD is an old thing and deprecated in C++20, you probably want to check for standard layout.

You can check that in your code writing

```
#include <type_traits>
static_assert(std::is_pod<A>::value, "");
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<A>::value, "");
```

or C++17 upwards

```
#include <type_traits>
static_assert(std::is_pod_v<A>);
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<A>);
```

Comment: The reason that I am interested in POD is so that I can make sure my objects are allocated in static memory. I am using C++11. With the deprecation, does this mean I am stuck with dynamic allocation? I will run these commands.